# Jquery accordion height overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jquery (v 1.11.4) ui accordion, which will ajax in different customer orders (of varying lengths) when opened. The problem I'm having is that because the content doesn't exist when the accordion is created, the height is not being set correctly and the content overlaps the accordion below.

I've tried changing autoheight between True/False, changing heightStyle between content, fill, panel, auto, "content" and "panel", and using both of them at the same time just in case.

HTML:

```
<div id="orders-accordion" class="account-details">
  <xsl:for-each select="//orderhistory/row">
    <div class="order-wrapper">
      <div class="order-accordion-header property-list" data-oid="{@orderid}">
        <ul>
          <li class="order-no">
            <span class="property-label">Order  No.</span>
            <span class="property-value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@orderid"/>
                                        </span>
          </li>
          <li class="order-date">
            <span class="property-label">Order Date</span>
            <span class="property-value">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="@orderdate"/>
                                        </span>
          </li>
          <li class="order-current-status">
            <span class="property-label">Order Status</span>
            <span class="property-value">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="@orderstatus"/>
                                        </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="order-info" style="display:none">
        <!-- Order Detail Ajaxed into here -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
      <script>
        bindClickToOrderBox('showTopBox');

      </script>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

JS

```
if ($('#orders-accordion').length > 0) {
  // Accordionise the Orders in the Order History
  $('#orders-accordion').accordion({
    //active: 0,
    header: ".order-accordion-header",
    collapsible: true,
    //autoHeight: true,
    heightStyle: "panel"

  });
}

function bindClickToOrderBox(showTopBox) {
  $('.order-wrapper div').click(function() {
    var content = $(this);
    $(content).siblings('.order-info').html('<div class="order-loading"></div>').show();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'default.aspx',
      data: 'Z=C&rnd=&serveas=ajax&action=history&oid=' + $(this).data('oid'),
      success: function(xhr) {
        $(content).siblings('.order-info').html(xhr);
        $('[name="tax-invoice-button"]', $(content).siblings('.order-info')).click(function() {
          $('#order_invoice_' + $(this).data('orderid')).attr('src', '/default.aspx?Z=C&action=history&oid=' + $(this).data('orderid') + '&mode=print');
        });
      }
    });
  });
  if (showTopBox) {
    var topOrderDiv = $('.order-wrapper div:first');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'default.aspx',
      data: 'Z=C&rnd=&serveas=ajax&action=history&oid=' + topOrderDiv.data('oid'),
      success: function(xhr) {
        topOrderDiv.siblings('.order-info').html(xhr).show();
        $('[name="tax-invoice-button"]', $(topOrderDiv).siblings('.order-info')).click(function() {
          $('#order_invoice_' + $(this).data('orderid')).attr('src', '/default.aspx?Z=C&action=history&oid=' + $(this).data('orderid') + '&mode=print');
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you fiddle this or too much effort?

Comment: Can't, workplace laptop. For some reason fiddle is not approved for use.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an *accordion refresh* after the ajax calls which modify the accordion contents, like so:

```
$("#orders-accordion").accordion("refresh");
```

That should resize the accordion on the page so that its content doesn't overflow into any elements appearing after it.